# Push Notification Service in database triggers Mongodb Stitch

Tags: mongodb, firebase, triggers, mongodb-stitch

I want to send push notification to android app in database trigger MongoDB Stitch.
In MongoDB Stitch Console there is a push notifications control and I can send new notification in there. But I want send new notification in triggers. Can you help me to find any tutorial about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a Stitch function by doing:

```
    context.services.get("gcm").send({
        "userIds": ["<userId>", ...],
        "priority": "normal",
        "notification": {
            "title": "hello, world",
            ...
        }
     });
```

These are just some of the fields you can use. You can find the rest in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/push-notifications/#push-notification-rules). I also found a [blog post](https://www.compose.com/articles/push-notifications-with-mongodb/) that isn't really what you're trying to do but might still help.