# What is best approach to polling a MongoDB database looking for changes

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, background-service, ihostedservice

I have two microservices (ServiceA and ServiceB).

- ServiceA inserts records into a MongoDB database.
- ServiceB check in MongoDB if there are new records and does some work with theses new records.

ServiceB is a backgroundservice, in `ExecuteAsync` method, I query MongoDB to check new records every second.

Is it a good approach to query the database every second? (Is it not too resource intensive? It's a select with where condition)

Otherwise, I was thinking of using RabbitMQ:

- ServiceA inserts records in MongoDB database and pushes message (Id of record) to RabbitMQ.
- ServiceB consumes RabbitMQ's message and does work.

Comment: Possibly of [interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644013/push-notification-service-in-database-triggers-mongodb-stitch)

Comment: I'd opt for the message queue, especially if the infrastructure is already in place.

Comment: Yes the infrastructure is already in place